# Communication Failure between Server and Client

Tags: python

Mission of the following two codes is to receive a string from Client, then add a timestamp, and finally send it back to the Client. I had run them in the right order(First Server, then Client), but nothing seems to happen after typing a string. Here are my codes:

1. tsTserv3.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from socket import *
from time import ctime
HOST = ''
PORT = 21565
BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

tcpSerSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
tcpSerSock.bind(ADDR)
tcpSerSock.listen(5)

while True:
    print('waiting for connection...')
    tcpCliSock, addr = tcpSerSock.accept()
    print('...connected from:', addr)

    while True:
        data = tcpCliSock.recv(BUFSIZ)
        if not data:
            break
        tcpCliSock.send('[%s] %s' % (
            bytes(ctime(), 'utf-8'), data))
        tcpCliSock.close()
    tcpSerSock.close()
```

2. tsTcint3.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from socket import *

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 21565
BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

tcpCliSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
tcpCliSock.connect(ADDR)

while True:
    data = input('> ').encode()
    if not data:
        break
    tcpCliSock.send(data)
    data = tcpCliSock.recv(BUFSIZ)
    if not data:
        break
    print(data.decode('utf-8'))

tcpCliSock.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked well when I change code in server as this:

```
tcpCliSock.send(f'{ctime()} {data}'.encode())
```

and **remove tab space once** in the **last two lines**.

So the final code of server will be like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from socket import *
from time import ctime
HOST = ''
PORT = 21565
BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

tcpSerSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
tcpSerSock.bind(ADDR)
tcpSerSock.listen(5)

while True:
    print('waiting for connection...')
    tcpCliSock, addr = tcpSerSock.accept()
    print('...connected from:', addr)

    while True:
        data = tcpCliSock.recv(BUFSIZ)
        if not data:
            break
        tcpCliSock.send(f'{ctime()} {data}'.encode())
    tcpCliSock.close()
tcpSerSock.close()
```

Comment: Your suggestion works! However, I noticed that there is an unwanted letter b before the string. How to get rid of it?

Comment: Use this method: `your_var = your_var.decode()`

Comment: ···tcpCliSock.send(f'{ctime()} {data.decode()}'.encode())···